# Sybase - Grant everyone access to a table

Tags: sybase, privileges

I need any user to be able to access a particular table in Sybase. In my case, the SELECT privilege is sufficient.

Is there a way to achieve that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GRANT SELECT ON my_table TO PUBLIC

Comment: If you have any rules about who can see what, PUBLIC is generally a bad idea and you'll need to read about GRANTs to users or roles.